# Update a production Sqlite database after publish

Tags: sqlite, continuous-integration, entity-framework-core, .net-core

We are trying to update the schema of an Sqlite database during continuous integration. Here is a simplified version of our scenario.

The deployment script publishes the project.

```
cd App
App> dotnet publish <args>
```

That creates the following directory structure.

```
artifacts/
    App.dll
    Database.sqlite
    The-rest-of-the-publish-output
    web.config                
App/
    Migrations/
    Program.cs
    project.json
    Startup.cs
```

The deployment script then runts the migrations.

```
App> dotnet ef 
  --assembly ..\artifacts\App.dll 
  --startup-assembly ..\artifacts\App.dll 
  database update
```

The issue is that we receive the following message:

```
Unexpected value '..\artifacts\App.dll' for option 'assembly'
```

We have also tried other ways to run `dotnet ef database update` on the compiled project but have not been able to determine how to update the database in the `artifacts` directory.

Answer (score 3):

In our current scenario, we do it like this on `Startup.cs`:

```
if (migrateDb)
{
    try
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
            .CreateScope())
        {
            serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

while on development `migrateDb` resolves to `false` so we can add/remove and apply migrations as desired. On production that will resolve to `true` for convenience.

There may be well more valid/appropiate options, usually depends on the context and/or project needs. This is just one way of many.